# how to run extensions in the magento

Tags: magento-1.9

i am a novice person to magento.I installed magneto 1.9.2.4 version.I need to create the extension for magento.I learned about the file structure of creating extension but cannot know how to run.Can anyone specify how to run the extension?
Advance Thanks!

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Multidots/HelloWorld/etc/config.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
  <modules>
  <Multidots_HelloWorld>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  </Multidots_HelloWorld>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
  <routers>
  <helloworld>
  <use>standard</use>
  <args>
  <module>Multidots_HelloWorld</module>
  <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
  </args>
  </helloworld>
  </routers>
  </frontend>
   <admin>
  <routers>
  <helloworld>
   <use>admin</use>
  <args>
   <module>Multidots_HelloWorld</module>
   <frontName>admin_helloworld</frontName>
   </args>
   </helloworld>
   </routers>
   </admin>
   </config>
```

/var/www/html/magento/app/etc/modules/Multidots_HelloWorld.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
<modules>
  <Multidots_HelloWorld>
     <active>true</active>
     <codePool>local</codePool>
  </Multidots_HelloWorld>
</modules>
 </config>
```

/var/www/html/magento/app/code/local/Multidots/HelloWorld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php
  class Multidots_HelloWorld_IndexController extends  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
 public function indexAction() {
   echo "Huhh...., I knew you can do it!!!n";
   echo "Let's do it in proper way, you konow... ;) :D :P";
    }
    }
  ?>
```

i run this code using http://localhost/magento/helloworld also http://localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld but i got error

```
Whoops, our bad...

  The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

    If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is   correct.
    If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

 What can you do?
Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on   track    with Magento Store.

    Go back to the previous page.
    Use the search bar at the top of the page to search for your products.
    Follow these links to get you back on track!
    Store Home | My Account
```

can anyone suggest how to run?

Comment: First check in the configuration->advanced menu whether your module is present of not

Comment: yes already is present. i just changed my url to run  localhost/magento/index.php/default/helloworld.thanks for your reply Mr.biblab rout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are asking for creating extension from scratch right?
Please check this link for creating simple extension.
http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/

And for run that extension please reload the front or backend of the Magento.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mr.Mayur .I  reload the front and back end still i got error "Whoops, our bad..." i used the url http://localhost/magento/index.php/inchoo-hellodeveloper to run the program.I just used the program what link you prefered for me.can any other way is present to got output please suggest me?

Comment: Which error you face? And please clear cache and run it?

Comment: And please read properly and copy the content from this link 
http://www.multidots.com/step-by-step-guide-for-magento-module-development

I write from it and it was work for me.

Comment: After a long time struggle i got the answer.url is http://localhost/magento/index.php/default/helloworld  thanks Mr.Mayur.i already used the above  link but the run url is not mentioned.Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: And Mam please check in the link there also run URL is mention please read it carefully. And thank for give me upvote.